# How do ros service responses work

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello everyone,

I have the following problem:

When I can call a service"server node" to calculate something(for simplicity float_A/float_B), how can i use the response to do something in my client node(for instance make a dissension in my state_2). The code of the server node and client node is given below. (.srv file float32[] a ------- float32[] sum)

```
#client node
class State_2(smach.State):

def __init__(self):
    smach.State.__init__(self, outcomes=['outcome1','outcome2'])
    
self.check = False
self.subscriber = rospy.Subscriber("chatter",Array, self.callback)

def callback(self,data):
self.ranges_list = list(data.ranges)

def execute(self, userdata):
rospy.sleep(1.0)
rospy.wait_for_service('check_teammember_behind_turtle')

check_teammember_behind_turtle = rospy.ServiceProxy('check_teammember_behind_turtle', teammember)
check_teammember_behind_turtle(self.ranges_list[0:3])
## THINK I MISS HERE SOMETHING##
    ## MAYBE YOU CAN HELP ME##


rospy.loginfo('Executing state STATE_2')
       
if self.check: 
    return 'outcome1'
else:
    return 'outcome2'

## CODE SERVER ##
def handle_teammember(req):
list_teammember = list(req.a)
tx = list_teammember[0]/list_teammember[1]
ty = list_teammember[1]/list_teammember[2]
if (tx>ty):
tx_list = [tx]
print ("tx")
else:
tx_list = [ty]
print ("ty")

return teammemberResponse(tx_list)

def add_two_ints_server():
rospy.init_node('add_two_ints_server')
s = rospy.Service('check_teammember_behind_turtle', teammember, handle_teammember)
print "Ready to add two ints."
rospy.spin()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10604/how-do-ros-service-responses-work./) by [boy](https://answers.ros.org/users/799/boy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2011-07-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [boy](https://answers.ros.org/users/799/boy/) on 2011-07-18**:
I will do that, SORRY!

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-07-18**:
Please try to make your head line informative next time. (I fixed this one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The response is returned by the call.
See this tutorial: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient(python)

You need to adapt this code to yours:

```
rospy.wait_for_service('add_two_ints')
try:
    add_two_ints = rospy.ServiceProxy('add_two_ints', AddTwoInts)
    resp1 = add_two_ints(x, y)
    return resp1.sum
except rospy.ServiceException, e:
    print "Service call failed: %s"%e
```

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-07-20**:
If it's working, accept the answer...karma karma karma!

**Comment by [boy](https://answers.ros.org/users/799/boy/) on 2011-07-17**:
I have it working :) Thanks

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-07-17**:
If the code above runs, you just change one line to: resp = check_teammember_behind_turtle(self.ranges_list[0:3]) and then handle the response resp. Obviously the try/catch would be advisable, but to just get the information this should work.

**Comment by [boy](https://answers.ros.org/users/799/boy/) on 2011-07-17**:
thats what I thought too, but I cannot adapt the code without getting a lot of errors. Maybe It's my lack in experience in python and ROS. Could you give me some more hints??

**Comment by [boy](https://answers.ros.org/users/799/boy/) on 2011-07-17**:
Thanks for the answer, but I still don't have it yet. Could you give me some hits or small example?? Reminder: I have to make a decision with the info obtained from server